API Automation of dot net based application
I need to work on API Automation of dot net based application. I am aware of rest assured, Is it possible to use rest assured for a dot net based application. Can anyone suggest.

I wouldn't expect a Java library to work as part of a .Net application.  But there's nothing stopping a Java-based client from using your API.

RestAssured is also available in .NET. You can use that. See https://github.com/basdijkstra/rest-assured-net
